# wget command working in linux but not working in windows

Tags: linux, windows, wget

I am trying to control IP Power Switch 9258 using wget command. using the ubuntu machine's wget i am able to power on and power off the IP Switch.

But if i use the same command in windows(GNU Wget 1.11 version) i am unable to turn on or turn off the ip power switch(IP 9258)

```
"wget http://admin:12345678\@192.168.0.49/Set.cmd?CMD=SetPower+P62=0;"


 D:\GIT\fence_ip9258>wget http://admin:12345678\@192.168.1.41/Set.cmd?CMD=SetPowe
r+P63=0
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2014-06-12 19:12:59--  http://admin:*password*@192.168.1.41/Set.cmd?CMD=SetPow
er+P63=0
Connecting to 192.168.1.41:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Connecting to 192.168.1.41:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authorization failed.
```

Just trying to understand what is happening here, Thanks in advance for your insight in understanding the problem

Regards
Hari

Comment: If you omit the backslash before the `@`, does it work?

Comment: add please description what actually happens on the console, when you start wget

Comment: hi flup, Thanks for suggestion it actually worked, the culprit was the backslash before @. The issue is solved, But how come in linux this issue is ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be in the escaping the '@' character.
In linux shells, any character can be escaped, including characters that don't need escapement. For example, "echo \@" and "echo @" produce the same result: '@'.
In Windows shell, "echo @" produces '@', but "echo \@" produces "\@".
Just remove that backslash.

Comment: Thanks oleg, for the insight,

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the backslash before @.

```
D:\GIT\fence_ip9258>wget http://admin:12345678@192.168.1.41/Set.cmd?CMD=SetPower
+P63=1
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2014-06-12 19:14:47--  http://admin:*password*@192.168.1.41/Set.cmd?CMD=SetPow
er+P63=1
Connecting to 192.168.1.41:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Connecting to 192.168.1.41:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified
Saving to: `Set.cmd@CMD=SetPower+P63=1'

    [ <=>                                   ] 58           311B/s   in 0.2s

2014-06-12 19:14:48 (311 B/s) - `Set.cmd@CMD=SetPower+P63=1' saved [58]
```